# Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao"

Tags: c#

I am getting below error when running given C# program:

> Warning MSB3283: Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library
>   "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao". Verify that (1) the COM
>   component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the
>   same as the bitness of the COM component. For example, if the COM
>   component is 32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit.

I am using Microsoft 365

I have removed the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.dll and add it back, reinstalled Microsoft office to 32-bit and ticked the 'registered COM interop' options in properties, but the issue still persist.

The error is refer to below default Microsoft MSBuild files.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2726,5)

I expected able to run the code successfully without error but it still return above error.

Comment: Did you compile your project using the 32bit target?

Comment: It is not obvious where the wrapper came from.  Wrong place, surely.  Ideally it doesn't exist at all, you always want to have the Embed Interop Types property set to True for Office references and have the interop types generated at build time.  Project > Add Reference > COM tab, select "Microsoft Office x.y Access Database Engine...".  x.y is 15.0 on my machine but I don't have Office 365 installed.

Comment: Yes. Tried compile in 32 bits as well still receive same error message